# How to find five input number closest to zero in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to java programming. Someone can teach how to get number closest to zero using `Scanner`. Example user inserts *first number=-4* , *second number=3* , and so on with *greater numbers*, then the *answer* close to zero is ***3***.

**Below is the code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class NearZero {

public static void main(String[]args) {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    int firstNumber,secondNumber,thirdNumber,fourNumber,fiveNumber;
    int nearNumberZero;


    System.out.println("Enter number 1");
    firstNumber = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number 2");
    secondNumber = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number 3");
    thirdNumber = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number 4");
    fourNumber = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number 5");
    fiveNumber = scn.nextInt();

    nearNumberZero =

    System.out.println("The number near zero 0 is");
}

}
```

Comment: "Someone can teach" This isn't a teaching site. You've got a good start, in terms of getting the numbers; but have a go and see how far you can get. Then come back with a specific question about why that didn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the **input** to your number in a `loop` as the operation is same and do like below,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class NearZero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        int nearNumberZero = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number " + i);
            number = scn.nextInt();
            // by default first is nearest or it will check for other numbers
            if (i == 1 || Math.abs(number) < Math.abs(nearNumberZero))
                nearNumberZero = number;
        }
        System.out.println("The number near zero 0 is - " + nearNumberZero);
        scn.close();//prefer closing your resources (with a try-finally preferrable)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
import java.util.*;

  class NearZero {

   public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();


    System.out.println("Enter number 1");
    integers.add(scn.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Enter number 2");
    integers.add(scn.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Enter number 3");
    integers.add(scn.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Enter number 4");
    integers.add(scn.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Enter number 5");
    integers.add(scn.nextInt());
    Collections.sort(integers, Comparator.comparingInt(Math::abs));

    System.out.println("The number near zero 0 is" + integers.get(0));
  } 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for OP's example input.

Comment: thanks Andy Turner I have missed some thing and fixed it

Comment: OK, it now works; but you don't need to put numbers into a list and sort them in order to find the min.

Comment: Yep it's true but I did the less codding change to Addy Sahaja implementation

Answer (score 1):

Simply compare them using Math.abs:

```
int bestNumber = firstNumber;
if (Math.abs(secondNumber) < Math.abs(bestNumber)) {
    bestNumber = secondNumber;
}
if (Math.abs(thirdNumber) < Math.abs(bestNumber)) {
    bestNumber = thirdNumber;
}
and so on...
```

Then finish off with:

```
System.out.println("The number near zero 0 is " + bestNumber);
```

Ideally, you should build a loop that asks for and compares the numbers, rather than repeating the same code five times. You can let that be your next exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any fancy comparators or lists.

Define a little helper method:

```
static int chooseClosestToZero(int a, int b) {
  return Math.abs(a) < Math.abs(b)) ? a : b;
}
```

Define a starting value whose absolute value is as far from zero as you can get (*):

```
int closestToZero = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

and now just call the method to update that:

```
System.out.println("Enter number 1");
closestToZero = chooseClosestToZero(closestToZero, scn.nextInt());

System.out.println("Enter number 2");
closestToZero = chooseClosestToZero(closestToZero, scn.nextInt());

// etc.
```

As noted by [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47921320/3788176), you can do this in a loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
  System.out.println("Enter number " + i);
  closestToZero = chooseClosestToZero(closestToZero, scn.nextInt());
}
```

---

(*) `chooseClosestToZero` doesn't quite work for one particular input - `Integer.MIN_VALUE` - since `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE`, because of the way `int`s are stored. To handle that case, you'd have to do something like:

```
static int chooseClosestToZero(int a, int b) {
  if (a == Integer.MIN_VALUE) return b;
  if (b == Integer.MIN_VALUE) return a;
  return Math.abs(a) < Math.abs(b)) ? a : b;
}
```

With this change, you can use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as the initial value of `closestToZero`, which is genuinely as far from zero as an `int` can be.